# self.view.bounds.maxY only works outside of viewDidLoad()

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

I am trying to adjust the size of my custom keyboard extension by using

```
self.view.bounds.maxY
```

However, the code only seems to work outside of

```
viewDidLoad()
```

Is there a way to go through viewDidLoad again after I have saved the height of my view?

Is there another way to get the height of the keyboard rectangle other than using the notifications?

Comment: The problem is that `viewDidLoad` is too soon. The real height of `self.view` is not yet known.

Comment: @matt At what point is the height of self.view known?

Comment: After `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UIScreen.main.bounds.height` which is the same as `self.view.bounds.maxY` assuming it's a full screen VC , otherwise access it inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

> Is there a way to go through viewDidLoad again after I have saved the height of my view?

yes , you can but it's not a good idea to call a method which should be called by the system

> Is there another way to get the height of the keyboard rectangle other than using the notifications?

no